# Adding a JPanel manually in NetBeans 7.1

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am trying to add a JPanel manually to a JPanel that was created via the Graphic Designer.
Since i can't edit in the Generated code i have no idea if i can do that.

```
private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     newBall2 = new BasketBall("BasketBall",20,400);
     MainpaintPanel mp = new MainpaintPanel();
     this.add(mp);
}
```

in this code the mp Panel is created successfully but it doesn't show where it's added.
i think it's related to the default Layout of the netBeans but it could be something else.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried `this.setContentPane(mp)?`

Comment: Show the code of your MainpaintPanel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also try using the ".setVisible(true)" and "setLocationRelativeTo(component c)" methods of the panel